# Error while restarting httpd in fedora 8

Tags: domain, subdomain, httpd, fedora

I want to create subdomain on my local machine(OS is **Fedora 8**) say `test.localhost`

Before i made following changes i started `httpd`.Open `localhost` in browser.It was showing `apache2` page.But i have not installed apache2.There is no directory like `apache2` under `etc`.
Should i install apache2?
I modified **httpd.conf** file by making following entry

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
127.0.0.1 test.localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/test/
# ErrorLog  /var/www/test/logs/error.log
#CustomLog /var/www/test/logs/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

I modified **host conf** by making entry

```
#127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 test.localhost
```

I have made entry in **name.conf** as follows

```
zone "test.localhost" {
  type master;
  file "/var/named/test.localhost"; 
};
```

So i have modified only 3 files and restarted `httpd` service. It is showing following error

> **Starting httpd: Syntax error on line 993 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:
>   Invalid command '127.0.0.1', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration**

**What is going wrong?**

**Can any one give me steps to create subdomain on local machine in linux(fedora 8)**

*Your response will be greatly appreciated !!*

Comment: Fedora 8? Are you serious?!

Comment: any idea how i can upgrade fedora 8 to 9/10? i tried but it is not working.

Comment: At this point? It's so old you should just install a fresh copy of a _current_ release of Fedora. Attempting to upgrade will be nothing less than a nightmare.

Comment: but at this point can it(what i have asked in question) be done with fedora 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your httpd.conf is damaged. A "ServerAliases" keyword somehow disappeared. A working version:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
ServerName test
ServerAlias 127.0.0.1 test.localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/test/
# ErrorLog  /var/www/test/logs/error.log
#CustomLog /var/www/test/logs/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```